# SQL Order by with multiple scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a complex SQL query and I want to manipulate resultant data based on certain conditions.

Here is a look at my data structure. It's a combination of 3 tables which allows storing of different activities and its registration period.

[image]

Here is a basic query (part of the more complex query):

```
select 
    act.ID, act.Name, arp.RegistrationPeriodId, 
    rp.StartDateTime, rp.EndDateTime 
from
    Activity act
join 
    ActivityRegistrationPeriod arp on arp.ActivityId = act.ID
join
    RegistrationPeriod rp on rp.Id = arp.RegistrationPeriodId
```

**What I want to achieve**

I have to order this data in below conditions, priority vise.

- Show programs that are now registering first, (so I guess it would be today is in between StartDateTime and EndDateTime)
- Closing soon, (end date is nearest to today)
- Opening soon (start data is nearest to today)

**What I tried so far**

I tried creating a temp table and storing data for each of these conditions (although that's not working properly) but I'm thinking of ordering it if possible and that's why I bring this issue here so a experienced SO can guide me.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

**Updated query:**

```
select 
    act.ID, act.Name, arp.RegistrationPeriodId, 
    rp.StartDateTime, rp.EndDateTime 
from
    Activity act
join 
    ActivityRegistrationPeriod arp on arp.ActivityId = act.ID
join
    RegistrationPeriod rp on rp.Id = arp.RegistrationPeriodId
--where 
--  act.AccountId = 3106
order by 
    (case when GETDATE() between StartDateTime and endDateTime then 1 else 2 end),
    (case when rp.EndDateTime is null then 2 else 1 end), 
    rp.EndDateTime asc,
    (case when rp.StartDateTime is null then 2 else 1 end), 
    rp.StartDateTime desc
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Please provide the sample date in editable text/tables - not pictures - and include the column headers. Please supply the output you are expecting to see (based on the sample data you provide) and the precise logic you want to use to derive the output

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've updated the question, basically it means first order will be if any activity that is registering currently. second will be those which are closing soon and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
order by (case when current_date between StartDateTime and endDateTime then 1 else 2 end),
         endDateTime asc,
         StartDateTime desc
```

Comment: thanks @gordon, looks like it will work but I still have to optimize it for null and other things.

Comment: @Bharat . . . I think this answers the question you asked here.

Comment: Gordon, can you please check updated query, I'm trying to bring non null value first through order by. is it good practice as what I did in query?

Comment: @Bharat . . . That seems reasonable.